# Why VAE in Keras has an exponential?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, tf.keras, autoencoder

In Keras VAE implementation:

```
class Sampling(layers.Layer):
    """Uses (z_mean, z_log_var) to sample z, the vector encoding a digit."""

  def call(self, inputs):
      z_mean, z_log_var = inputs
      batch = tf.shape(z_mean)[0]
      dim = tf.shape(z_mean)[1]
      epsilon = tf.keras.backend.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
      return z_mean + tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon
```

My question is about the "`tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var)`" part: why we used the exponential and not just have the var as it is? I mean why not just: return `z_mean + z_log_var * epsilon`

I want to know why `tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var)` and not just `z_log_var`?

I am using it for tabular data and not images. I mean, I am using dense layers and not Conv layers.

Comment: Because variance has to be positive, and the inverse of log-variance is exponential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as you can guess from the name, the encoder outputs the log variance. Thereby, we ensure that the variance is always positive (`exp(z_log_var) >= 0`), because the e function is always positive.

The part that is done in this snippet is called the *reparameterization trick* (as discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199605/how-does-the-reparameterization-trick-for-vaes-work-and-why-is-it-important#:%7E:text=Reparameterization%20trick%20is%20a%20way,(%CE%B8%2B%CF%B5)2%5D)). The key idea for normal distributions is that any normal distribution can be expressed by sampling from a standard gaussian distribution and shifting it as follows `z = mu + sigma * epsilon` with `epsilon ~ N(0,1)`. For this, we need the standard deviation, `exp(0.5 * z_log_var)` converts the log variance to the standard deviation.